# insert node_modules assets into my project

Tags: node.js, webpack, aws-lambda

I'm using webpack to build my lambda functions, but there is a package with loads a `.proto` extension file and I can't import it into my project so I'm getting file not found error. This is called inside node_modules folder like:

```
  path.join(__dirname, 'checkin.proto');
```

My webpack output is just a `index.js` file, so there isn't any checkin.proto file to load.

This is my `webpack.config.js` to build my lambdas. This basically transcript `ts` to `js`, build an bundled `index.js` and zip it.

```
const glob = require('glob');
const path = require('path');
const ZipPlugin = require('zip-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  console.log(`Buiding in ${argv.mode} mode`);

  const functionsToBuild = glob
    .sync('./src/lambdas/*/index.*')
    .map(x => x.match(/(?<=src\/lambdas\/).*/)[0]);

  return functionsToBuild.map(fxn => {
    const lambdaName = fxn.split('/')[0];
    const triggerName = fxn.split('/')[1];

    return {
      entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'lambdas', lambdaName, triggerName),
      devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
      output: {
        filename: 'index.js',
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist', lambdaName),
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
      },
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
            use: [
              'ts-loader'
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
      },
      optimization: {
        minimize: false,
        namedModules: true
      },
      plugins: [
        new ZipPlugin({
          path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist', lambdaName),
          pathPrefix: '',
          filename: `${lambdaName}.zip`
        })
      ],
      externals: {
        'aws-sdk': 'aws-sdk',
        'awslambda': 'awslambda',
        'dynamodb-doc': 'dynamodb-doc',
        'imagemagick': 'imagemagick'
      },
      target: 'node',
      node: {
        __filename: false,
        __dirname: false
      },
      stats: 'errors-only',
      bail: true,
    }
  });
}
```

How can I load this file or at least doesn't touch in `node_modules` structure?

Comment: try this plugin to copy it maybe https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin. I haven't actually tried it yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

1) don't bundle the .proto file into the bundled JS, but instead copy the source .proto file out to your build destination by means of the https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin. This should allow you to use your existing methods to fetching this file's data and parsing still.

2) do bundle this .proto file into the bundled JS by means of a webpack loader plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/proto-loader or possibly https://www.npmjs.com/package/raw-loader. This however will require you do away with your existing fetching approach and may or may not need you to update parsing logic of the bundled data.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's it man. Using `copy-webpack-plugin` worked. Your second approach is actually not viable because .proto file isn't imported or required.